# Figuring out the real Java heap on AWS Fargate

Tags: java, docker, aws-fargate

We have a container (task) running in AWS Fargate and we see some weird behavior where memory don't seem to be utilized correctly so I've been trying to figure out how this is actually set/used...

The task is set to 2vCPU/4GB memory.

The app is a Tomcat running on Java and memory is set to 80% for Java (`-XX:MaxRAMPercentage=80.0`) but somehow this is seems to be altered by Tomcat to:

```
echo $CATALINA_OPTS
-Xms1g -Xmx4g -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom
```

Tomcat/Catalina thus shows `Xmx4g` for the container with max. 4GB memory.

However trying to figure out what is really used in the container has proven a bit difficult but looking in the container itself:

```
root@ip-172-31-28-76:/home/git# java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep HeapSize
   size_t ErgoHeapSizeLimit                        = 0                                         {product} {default}
   size_t HeapSizePerGCThread                      = 43620760                                  {product} {default}
   size_t InitialHeapSize                          = 67108864                                  {product} {ergonomic}
   size_t LargePageHeapSizeThreshold               = 134217728                                 {product} {default}
   size_t MaxHeapSize                              = 1073741824                                {product} {ergonomic}
    uintx NonNMethodCodeHeapSize                   = 5825164                                {pd product} {ergonomic}
    uintx NonProfiledCodeHeapSize                  = 122916538                              {pd product} {ergonomic}
    uintx ProfiledCodeHeapSize                     = 122916538                              {pd product} {ergonomic}
openjdk version "11.0.13" 2021-10-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.13+8)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.13+8, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Here it looks like the `MaxHeapSize` is `1GB` (1073741824 bytes)

Outputting the `docker stats` from the container through Fargate gives me a `Limits.Memory: 4096` as expected but then the memory stats are werird:

```
"memory_stats": {
        "usage": 541478912,
        "max_usage": 546689024,
        "stats": {
            "active_anon": 531214336,
            "active_file": 249856,
            "cache": 270336,
            "dirty": 0,
            "hierarchical_memory_limit": 4294967296,
            "hierarchical_memsw_limit": 9223372036854771712,
            "inactive_anon": 0,
            "inactive_file": 3846144,
            "mapped_file": 0,
            "pgfault": 156816,
            "pgmajfault": 0,
            "pgpgin": 149259,
            "pgpgout": 18544,
            "rss": 535040000,
            "rss_huge": 0,
            "total_active_anon": 531214336,
            "total_active_file": 249856,
            "total_cache": 270336,
            "total_dirty": 0,
            "total_inactive_anon": 0,
            "total_inactive_file": 3846144,
            "total_mapped_file": 0,
            "total_pgfault": 156816,
            "total_pgmajfault": 0,
            "total_pgpgin": 149259,
            "total_pgpgout": 18544,
            "total_rss": 535040000,
            "total_rss_huge": 0,
            "total_unevictable": 0,
            "total_writeback": 0,
            "unevictable": 0,
            "writeback": 0
        },
        "limit": 9223372036854771712
    }
```

What gives here?

Is the "true" max heap only 1GB as shown in `grep HeapSize`?

**EDIT #1**: Running the container command for stats for Fargate `curl ${ECS_CONTAINER_METADATA_URI_V4}/stats` I can see that "max. memory used" is actually 2.4GB so the shown MaxHeapSize as 1GB is not correct!

**EDIT #2**: Mangaed to get it to accept `-Xms1g -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=80.0` after some testing and now `MaxHeapSize` shows as 2GB.
I've up'ed the container to 2vCPU/8GB but the running mem stats still shows that max mem used is **2.4GB** so regardless of settings/changes it is not using more than the 2.4GB...

Comment: This is an interesting question that I'd like to learn the answer too?  Any update?

Comment: Sorry, no... I had two separate tickets with AWS support but never got a clear answer. We ended up running the applications on ECS with EC2 instead of Fargate... :(

Answer (score 0):

Suggest to investigate the meaning of [metaspace](https://www.javainuse.com/java/metaspace).

Configure metaspace with JVM option:   `-XX:MetaspaceSize`

Suggest to follow this formula:

> Available RAM = 512M(for OS) + 256M(for Tomcat metaspace) + JVM heap

Comment: Sorry, I don't really follow how this would help me figuring out how much memory the JAva process actually has available or the "true" heap size of Java... Can you explain a bit more please?